# Computer regularly locking up after startup

Tags: windows-10, freeze, hardware-failure

Saturday night, my PC started locking up. One second I was playing a game, the next, the cursor is frozen and it's not responding to any input.

It's continuing to happen. I can't use my PC for more than 10 minutes before it locks up. There are no errors in the event log other than that it wasn't shut down properly.

**Original Specs:**

- Windows 10 Pro 64-bit
- ASUS Z170-Pro
- i7-6700k
- EVGA 1070 FTW Gaming ACX 3.0
- 32GB (4x8gb) G.Skill Trident Z
- Samsung EVO 960 1TB m.2 SSD
- NZXT H440 Case
- Coolmaster CPU cooler (don't remember exactly which one)
- Corsair AX860 PSU

**New Specs:**

- *Windows 10 Pro 64-bit* (though has been reinstalled several times, with a disk wipe each time)
- MSI MPG X570 Gaming Edge
- Ryzen 9 3900X
- *EVGA 1070 FTW Gaming ACX 3.0* (eliminated as problem by removing and running on on-board video)
- 32GB (2x16gb) G.Skill Ripjaws V DDR4-3600
- Samsung EVO 970 1TB m.2 SSD
- *NZXT H440 Case*
- NZXT Kraken X72 AIO Watercooled CPU cooler
- Corsair HX1000i PSU

(unchanged items marked with italics)

**Things I've tried while troubleshooting:**

- Reinstall Windows
- Remove everything not essential (including GPU, and ran off of the
  on-board video)
- Reset the BIOS to factory settings
- Install windows on a separate SATA HDD
- Different KB/Mouse
- Replace CPU/Motherboard/RAM
- Replace PSU
- Unplug audio and USB Headers
- Replace power cord
- Replace surge protector
- Use a different monitor
- Move the computer to a different outlet
- Switch to a wireless connection
- Switch to using my phone as a hotspot
- Add an AIO liquid CPU cooler
- Move to a different circuit in the house
- Turn every circuit off and on again in the house, including the main breaker (after unplugging all of the electronics in the house)

Note: I've reinstalled Windows several times as hardware was swapped out.

No matter what I've tried, it still freezes in exactly the same way that it started on Saturday night. I'm at my wits end, and am looking for any and all ideas on what I can try to fix this. I can throw more money at it if I need to, but I'd prefer not to since I'm already in it over $1500.

New development! I managed to get an actual BSOD, but nothing notable in the event log.

Does anyone have any ideas ?

Edit: More new info. MemTest86 runs to completion without issue. CPU stress test tools die almost instantly.

I don't believe that the CPU is at fault though. The same thing happens with two different CPUs.

Edit 2: I was able to run prime95 for about 30 minutes or so, while gradually stepping up the number of threads. I haven't found the limit, however the CPU was up to about 85C and still working fine. Thus far, it doesn't appear to be heat related. If I set prime95 to 24 threads (the default on this system), it hangs almost immediately.

Of course, the second I actually try and *use* the PC, it hangs again. In this case, I tried to install Chrome.

Comment: Despite the downvote:\ I'd say you've done pretty much all that can be expected. Next step would be take it to a qualified repairer.

Comment: So I would recommend some tests. First run MemTest86 (to test your memory) for a couple days, seeing if it freezes during this or reports any errors. Secondly run something like FurMark to test your video card similarly. This overall approach is trying to test one component at a time to find the culprit. Also take a look in your BIOS to get an idea of what temperatures you are reaching

Comment: The fact that you got a BSOD immediately makes me think hardware issue so testing memory followed by harddrive might be a good idea. Even new memory can experience issues. Did you ensure the memory timing matches what the motherboard can handle? Is it a supported manufacturer for the memory as well? I am just trying to tick the boxes of what it could be

Comment: Did you do a chkdsk /R c: to check for disk errors?  Can you sit at your desktop for >10 minutes without freezing?  Have you monitored the 5v and 12v channel?  Also the GPU temperatures?

Comment: If you run furmark does it seize in 10min or less than that? How much less/more?  Can you run a CPU only benchmark >10 mins like prime95?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik No, I haven't, however I've deleted all of the partitions on the original drives and installed, and when that didn't work, I installed on a fresh drive. I don't believe that any potential malware could still be present after that. That said, the computer doesn't stay running long enough to do a malware scan.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104626/discussion-between-ficertyn-and-ramhound).